# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python, lista, validación, clase, excepciones

Estoy aprendiendo programación con Python. Tengo una clase CRUD_Users(), estoy aprendiendo ahora a validar entradas. Ya valide solo texto ahora tengo problemas para validar solo dígitos. Tengo las validaciones en funciones para usarlas en ámbito global cuando las necesite instanciar. Si les quito el 'int' a valores numéricos si ingresa, pero cuando realizo la búsqueda del usuario en otro método me dice que no existe aunque trate de retornarlo el valor como entero
Link permanente de la practica realizada: [CRUD.Users](https://pastebin.com/LY62xp5E)

```
lista_usuarios = []

class CRUD_Users():
    def __init__(self, listaUsers):
        self.listaUsers = listaUsers

    def obtener_datos_usuario(self):
        clear()
        global ID
            
        print("[Agregar usuario al sistema]\n\n")

        for i in range(1):
            #Usamos diccionario para establecer datos especificos y orden del usuario
            usr_prototype = {
                'ID'       : '',
                'Nombres'  : '',
                'Apellidos': '',    
                'Edad'     : '',
                'Cedula'   : ''
            }
            """
            El diccionario se encontraba fuera del bucle antes de la clase. No procedia almacenar valores. Solo era reemplazado. Se movio dentro del bucle. Por cada iteración ahora reconocera el dict, almacenará los datos y se envía a la lista.
            """
            usr_prototype['Nombres'] = input("Nombres: ")
            validarLetra = validarLetras(usr_prototype['Nombres'])

            usr_prototype['Apellidos'] = input("Apellidos: ")
            validarLetra = validarLetras(usr_prototype['Apellidos'])

            usr_prototype['Edad'] = input("Edad: ")
            validarNum = validarNumeros(usr_prototype['Edad'])

            usr_prototype['Cedula'] = input("Cédula: ")
            validarNum = validarNumeros(usr_prototype['Cedula'])
            #Antes de proceder a guardar el usuario se validará la cédula. Es una llave única de cada usuario

            validador_Users = self.validarID_Usuario(usr_prototype["Cedula"])

            if validador_Users:
                #Si el retorno es True
                print("\n[ERROR]: La cedula que desea registrar ya existe en el sistema.\nSi el programa presenta problemas técnicos comuniquese con el Soporte.\n\n")
                inPausa = EnterPause()
                break
            else:
                #Si el retorno es False
                print("¡Usuario registrado exitosamente!\n\n [DATOS]")
                ID += 1
                usr_prototype["ID"] = ID
                self.listaUsers.append(usr_prototype)
                self.mostrar_datos_usuario(usr_prototype["Cedula"])
                #Pasamos por parametro la cedula de la lista ingresada para mostrar los datos
```

```
def mostrar_datos_usuario(self, ced):
        user_found = False
        for i in self.listaUsers:
            if i["Cedula"] == ced:
                for key, value in i.items():
                    print(f"{key}: {value}")
                    user_found = True
                break       
        if not user_found:
            print("Cédula no registrada.")
        #Se quito el else y se movio el print fuera del bucle. Si la condicion no se cumple termina el bucle y muestra el msj 
        inPausa = EnterPause()
```

EDIT:

```
def validarNumeros(validarNum):
    it_Num = validarNum
    if not all(i.isdigit() for i in it_Num):
        it_Num = ""
        while not it_Num.isdigit():
            print("ERROR: Solo se permiten numeros. Intente nuevamente\n")
            it_Num = input("Ingresar: ")
            if all(i.isdigit() for i in it_Num):
                validarNum = int(it_Num)
                break
            else:
                pass
    return int(it_Num)
```

Comment: Tal como tienes el código, primero conviertes la entrada a entero y, después, pasas la entrada a la función validadora. Tendrás que hacerlo al revés: primero validar y después convertir. Por otro lado, de lo que hablas de la _búsqueda de usuario_ no podemos hacer nada si no añades el código que falla.

Comment: ¿Por qué el argumento es la misma función? `def validarNumeros(validarNumeros):`

Comment: Cambie el argumento. Vi esa falla y es poco legible. El arg es validarNum

Comment: No pongas esto como comentario, mejor añádelo a la pregunta. No sé a qué te refieres con "mostrar el usuario". Completa el código para que podamos probarlo y encontrar dónde te sale esos resultados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta era más sencilla. Lo que pasaba es que insistía en que edad y cedula debian tener int(input)

> usr_prototype['Edad'] = input("Edad: ")

Y reescribia mucho la función de validar una y otras vez. Lo hacia diferente dandome el mismo resultado. De la misma, me respondieron que debía invertir el orden, Primero debo validar y después convertir.

```
usr_prototype['Edad'] = validarNumeros("Edad: ")
usr_prototype['Cedula'] = validarNumeros("Cedula: ")
```

No tenía idea que podia pasar por parametros validarNumeros usando la variable del dict. Mayormente usaba una variable que no estuviera utilizada o que "afectara al dict"

```
def validarNumeros(validarNum):
    while True:
        var = input(validarNum)
        if var.isdigit():
            return int(var)
        else:
            print("ERROR: Solo se permiten numeros. Intente nuevamente")
```

la función fue simplificada. Lo que pasa es que cedula es un documento único de identidad. Cuando agregaba una letra/palabra me retornaba aunque las validaciones lo negaran y si ponía numero, en el momento de buscar al usuario este "No existe" aunque estuviera "registrado" (cosa que sí puesto que al registrar, muestra los datos del usuario).

Edit:
Luego que pudiera solucionar la entrada de datos. Ahora si pude adaptar correctamente la captura de excepciones, cumpliendo su cometido que haciendo validaciones de retorno True/False

```
def validarLetras(validarLetra):
while True:
    try:
        entrada = input(validarLetra)
        if entrada.isalpha():
            return entrada
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"ERROR: {validarLetra}debe contener solo letras. Intente nuevamente")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

def validarNumeros(validarNum):
while True:
    try:
        entrada = int(input(validarNum))
        if entrada >0:              
            return entrada
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"ERROR: {validarNum} debe ser un número. Intente nuevamente")
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```